# Why index is not used for Group by and/or Join when key exists on the column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.prodno AS id, 
       proddesc AS label 
FROM   product p 
       JOIN sales s 
         ON s.custno = 00800 
            AND s.deptno = 0 
            AND s.prodno = p.prodno 
GROUP  BY p.prodno 
ORDER  BY p.prodno ASC
```

Explain returns this:

```
+---+-----------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
| 1 |  'SIMPLE' |  'p' |  'ALL' |  'PRIMARY'                                                                   |  ''        |  ''  |  ''                                    |  481 |  100.00 |  'Using temporary; Using filesort' |
| 1 |  'SIMPLE' |  's' |  'ref' |  'PRIMARY,in_sales_custnodeptnoprodno,in_sales_deptnocustno,in_sales_custno' |  'PRIMARY' |  '6' |  'const,const,bkp_teststats2.p.PRODNO' |   93 |  100.00 |  'Using index'                     |
+---+-----------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

As you see there is no index used in the first row for PRODNO, but the table schema has index on it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `PRODNO` decimal(4,0) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `PRODDESC` char(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `UPCCODE12` decimal(12,0) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '000000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PRODNO`)
)
```

And sales has these keys:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTNO`,`DEPTNO`,`PRODNO`,`ARDATE8N`),
KEY `in_sales_custnodeptnoprodno` (`CUSTNO`,`DEPTNO`,`PRODNO`),
KEY `in_sales_deptnocustno` (`DEPTNO`,`CUSTNO`),
KEY `in_sales_custno` (`CUSTNO`),
```

I would like to drop `Using temporary; Using filesort` because the above query takes 14 seconds on a 50G data table.

**Update:**

Problem: I want to get a unique product list that have sales data for a given custno and deptno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database has to check every row in the `product` table to satisfy your query.  If it used the index, it would have to go back to the main table for every row to pick up `proddesc`.  Going back to the main table (a "bookmark lookup") is quite expensive.  So the query optimizer chooses to scan and sort the main table, which seems like a good choice to me.

If you omit `proddesc` from the result, the query only requires `prodno`.  In that case the query optimizer will probably use the index.

You could also expand the index on `products` from `(prodno)` to `(prodno, proddesc)`.  Expanded this way, the index can satisfy the query without table lookups.

Comment: Indeed, plus would also add that mysql is probably the one of "mature" relation databases that allow to select the field that is not used in `GROUP BY` or aggregation functions, thus - the more difficult to optimize such queries.

Comment: Can I do this in two selects? Maybe first select just the `prodno`, and then join the virtual table again to get the `proddesc`. Would that help?

Comment: @zerkms Group by is used for Distinct alternative, as in this scenario is faster than distinct

Comment: @Pentium10: you haven't described what actually you want to do.

Comment: @Pentium10: well, if it is *faster* - then why are you here? And if it is not fast enough - why did not you start with comprehensive explanation of what you have now and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get a unique product list that have sales data for a given custno and deptno.

Comment: @zerkms As I said in the question, the query takes 14 seconds to complete, I want to optimize that.

Comment: @Pentium10: That is precisely what MySQL is doing already, `using temporary` means it's creating a temporary table to store the results from `Products`.  So my quess is that wouldn't help :)

Comment: "I want to get a unique product list" --- query unique product ids using only one table - `sales`

Comment: My product list needs to include the description too.

Comment: @Pentium10: try to perform what I said for first. If it will give good results - let's try to extract the description on second the step, and doesn't matter how - subquery or second query with list of ids.

Comment: Adding index to `(prodno, proddesc)` is better.

Comment: @Pentium10: well, actually it is not ;-) But if you think so and even have not tried another advices - it is your wish ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Add your own better answer and I will consider it.

Comment: @Pentium10: I have already given it 3 comments above. But you'd better add unnecessary field to the index to solve your issue, instead of rewriting query.

Comment: As said 3 comments block above I've added an index on proddesc, and it works better.

Comment: @Pentium10: it cannot work better. Looking through 2 parts of index cannot be better than looking through 1 part of **the same** index.

Comment: @zerkms It works much better as it resolves the query just by using indexes, without table access.

Comment: @Pentium10: oops, missed that. Silly me.